# Type mismatch for Shape variable in VB

Tags: vb.net, excel

I am trying to go through each CommandButton on a worksheet. But I keep getting the Type Mismatch error when I try to run my function. I really dont know what mistake I am making here. Could someone please help me.

```
Sub Worksheet_Calculate()


Dim s As Shape
Dim findShape As String

findShape = "Not Found" 
For Each s In Me.Shapes
    If Intersect(s.TopLeftCell.Address, Range("D8:D21,D52:D64,D107:D117")) = True Then
      findShape = s.Name
        MsgBox findShape, vbOKOnly
        Else
        MsgBox "The active cell does Intersect "

     End If
Next
```

Comment: I answered below, but you probably should have updated [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30602539/how-to-verify-if-cell-address-falls-within-a-specified-range) with the code from above that way people have context for the question.  Also that other question is now likely to die an unanswered death.

Comment: @Bryon sorry about that . I'm new to the forum.

Answer (score 1):

You are not using `Intersect` correctly.  `Intersect` returns the *`Range`* which is the intersection of two other ranges.  If you want to know that the two `Ranges` have something in common, you check that the result is not `Nothing`.  Specifically you do:

```
Dim s As Shape
Dim findShape As String

findShape = "Not Found"
For Each s In Me.Shapes
    If Not Intersect(s.TopLeftCell, Range("D8:D21,D52:D64,D107:D117")) Is Nothing Then
        findShape = s.Name
        MsgBox findShape, vbOKOnly
    Else
    MsgBox "The active cell does Intersect "

    End If
Next
```

Note that I have also removed `.Address` from `TopLeftCell`.  `Intersect` works on `Ranges` which is what `TopLeftCell` already is.  `Address` returns a string which is not what `Intersect` wants.  I think this error is actually what's causing the run time error, although the incorrect usage of `Intersect` would be next.